# JPA/Hiberante don't generate join sql for FetchType.EAGER while Spring @Transactional annotated

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactional

I have a very wired problem.

JPA/Hiberante don't generate join sql for FetchType.EAGER while Spring @Transactional annotated. But if I remove the @Transactional . Everything is fine.

Here is the code:

```
public class Item {
    @ManyToOne
    private Order order;
}   

public class Order {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Item> items;
}   




@Test
@Transactional
public void testFetch() throws Exception {
     Item randomItem = new Item();
     Order randomOrder = new Order();

    //OrderService and itemService is implemented by Spring Roo standard. 
    orderService.saveOrder(randomOrder);
    randomItem.setOrder(randomOrder);
    itemService.saveItem(randomItem);


    Order OrderResult = orderService.findOrder(randomOrder.getId());
    final List<Item> itemSearchResult = OrderResult.getItems();

    Assert.assertNotNull(itemSearchResult);

}
```

The assertNotNull will fail if @Transactional on. But will success if @Transactional commented.

I debug more information. Just to find out when @Transactional on Hibernate will not generate join sql for

```
orderService.findOrder(randomOrder.getId());
```

Alos I try to switch to elicpseLink as JPA provider. Things become worse, when @Transactional commented, orderService.findOrder(randomOrder.getId()) will return a empty list(not null, size 0).

Any advice?  Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the joins in Hibernate except that you should specify fetch join in your query to be portable to other JPA providers.  EclipseLink in particular does not join eager relationships without JPA settings or native query hints or @JoinFetch annotations.

As for the collection being empty on EclipseLink.  This is because you only setting one side of the relationship. JPA requires you to set both sides of bidirectional relationships so that they remain consistent with what is in the database.  When @Transactional is commented out, you are getting back the same randomOrder instance that had an empty items collection when persisted.

Try calling randomOrder.addItems(randomItem); and randomItem.setOrder(randomOrder); before the orderService.saveOrder(randomOrder);  call.

Comment: 1 The code get the same result in Hibernate and eclipseLink. I know if I build bi-direction relationship it will works.